# Filling and submiting form with php curl

Tags: php, forms, curl

I am trying to fetch some data from one device.
Problem is that this device doesnt have snmp, event telnet doesnt have. Only web.
Web auth form made from one text input field and submit button. So there is no username and password. Only password and submit.
From page source i can see that there is also a java script in .
My idea is to do login, fetch information from page and parse it(no problems with parsing, have exp with this).
But what is confusing for me is how to paste password and "press" submit button and then fetch response.
HTML code of page:
Form where should be placed password, for example 1234

```
<input id="psw_id" type="password" maxlength="15" size="20" name="q" value="">
```

Then there is a submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="" name="q" class="w_bok">
```

And one strange element is

```
<input id="hpsw_id" type="hidden" name="pA" value="1C755EC55250421A">
```

And script in

```
    function DoHash()
    {
      var psw = document.getElementById('psw_id');
      var hpsw = document.getElementById('hpsw_id');
      var nonce = hpsw.value;
      hpsw.value = MD5(nonce.concat(psw.value));
      psw.value = '';
      return true;
    }
```

I see in firefox console POST message

```
POSThttp://10.168.168.144/CONTROL.HTM
```

And following values

```
q=&q=&pA=8142bb8f7976bfacaef515001405fa9f
```

Can somebody help me with making php curl query for login and fetching information from CONTROL.HTM?

Comment: More details required perhaps. Does `control.htm` set the `allow-origin` header that would allow a CORS fetch request? If not you could probably read the file using `file_get_contents` or directly into DOMDocument. If you can read by either of the latter two options mentioned then you can parse the document to find that hidden input and then easily create a new MD5 hash using that value and the password

Comment: `q=&q=&pA=8142bb8f7976bfacaef515001405fa9f` - so this is not sending the actual password field value, but only this calculated `pa` value. So you will have to do the same - and then means you will have to _request_ the form first, to get that initial `pA` value first, so that you can calculate the hash based on that plus the entered password. And most likely this initial `pA` value also gets stored in a session - so you will have to implement cookies in your cURL request as well then.